# Printing varchar php variable inside the javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, string, varchar

I am trying to print a variable value within the javascript function. If the variable is an integer ($myInteger) it works fine, but when I want to access text ($myText) it gives an error.

```
<?php $myText = 'some text';
    $myInteger = '220';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

<?php print("var myInteger = " . $myInteger . " ;\n");?> //works fine
<?php print("var myText = " . $myText . " ;\n");?> //doens't work

</script>
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happens and how to change it?

Comment: paste more code so I can see what you are trying to do...

Comment: Do you mean that you change the table column in the database from `INT` to `VARCHAR`? In that case, you need to show us how you get the value out of the database and into `$myText` -- that's probably where the problem is.

Comment: What error? whats in $myText? is it quoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code from the question is that the generated Javascript code will be missing quotes around the string.

You could add quotes to the output manually, as follows:

```
print("var myText = '". $myText. "';\n");
```

However, note that this will break if the string itself contains quotes (or new-line characters, or a few others), so you need to escape it.

This can be dealt with using the `addslashes()` function, among others, but this may still have issues.

A better approach would be to use PHP's built-in JSON functionality, which is designed specifically for generating Javascript variables, so it will do all the escaping for you correctly.

The function you're looking for is [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). You'd use it as follows:

```
print("var myText = ". json_encode($myText). ";\n");
```

This will work with any variable type -- integer, string, or even an array.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Without more code we don't really know what you're trying to do or what error you're getting (or from where even), but if I had to guess:

If you are putting a string of text into a javascript variable, you probably need to quote it.

```
<?php print("var myText = '" . $myText . "' ;\n");?>
                      ---^^^-------------^^^----

// Or even better:
<?php print("var myText = '$myText' ;\n");?>
```

**ADDENDUM** Per the comment below, don't use this if you expect your `$myText` to contain quotes.

Comment: -1 because this will break horribly if `$myText` contains a quote character.